# What is the Real $n$ th derivative of $1/(1+x^2)$ in the interval $(0,1) \: ?$

Tags: real-analysis

In the real interval $(0, 1)$, I could only find a complex values expression for the $n$ th derivative of $1/(1 + x^2)$. Which is weird because $1/(1 + x^2)$ is real on that interval. My attempt:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1+x^2} = \frac{1}{(1+ix)(1-ix)} = 
\frac{i}{2(x+i)} - \frac{i}{2(x-i)} = \frac{i}{2} \left(\frac{1}{x+i} - \frac{1}{x-i}\right).
\end{align*}

Using a software

\begin{align*}
& \left(\frac{1}{x+i}\right)^{(1)} = - \frac{1}{(x+i)^2} 
\hspace{27pt} \left(\frac{1}{x-i}\right)^{(1)} = - \frac{1}{(x-i)^2}\\
& \left(\frac{1}{x+i}\right)^{(2)} =  \frac{2}{(x+i)^3} 
\hspace{35pt} \left(\frac{1}{x-i}\right)^{(2)} =  \frac{2}{(x-i)^3}\\
& \left(\frac{1}{x+i}\right)^{(3)} = - \frac{6}{(x+i)^4}
\hspace{27pt} \left(\frac{1}{x-i}\right)^{(3)} =  \frac{6}{(x-i)^3}\\
& \left(\frac{1}{x+i}\right)^{(4)} =  \frac{24}{(x+i)^4} 
\hspace{35pt} \left(\frac{1}{x-i}\right)^{(4)} =  \frac{24}{(x-i)^3} \\
& \hspace{57pt} \vdots \hspace{130pt}  \vdots \\
& \left(\frac{1}{x+i}\right)^{(n)} = (-1)^n \frac{n!}{(x+i)^{n+1}}
\quad \left(\frac{1}{x-i}\right)^{(n)} = (-1)^n \frac{n!}{(x-i)^{n+1}}.
\end{align*}

So we have
\begin{align*}
&\left( \frac{1}{1+x^2} \right)^{(n)} = \frac{i}{2} {n! (-1)^n}\left( \frac{1}{(x+i)^{n+1}} - \frac{1}{(x-i)^{n+1}} \right).
\end{align*}

Witring in polar form $x+i = re^{it}$, we can simplify the above to
\begin{align*}
{n! (-1)^n} \frac{i}{2}\left( \frac{1}{(x+i)^{n+1}} - \frac{1}{(x-i)^{n+1}} \right) 
&= {n! (-1)^n} \frac{i}{2}\left( \frac{1}{(re^{it})^{n+1}} - \frac{1}{(re^{-it})^{n+1}} \right) \\
&= \frac{n! (-1)^n}{r^{n+1}} \frac{i}{2} \left( \frac{1}{(e^{it})^{n+1}} - \frac{1}{(e^{-it})^{n+1}} \right)\\
&= \frac{n! (-1)^n}{r^{n+1}} \frac{i}{2} \left( {(e^{-i})^{t(n+1)}} - {(e^{i})^{t(n+1)}} \right)
\end{align*}

noticing that
\begin{align*}
\sin \theta = \frac{i}{2}
\left( {e^{-i\theta}} - {e^{i\theta}} \right)
\end{align*}

and making $\theta = t(n+1)$ the $n$ th derivative becomes
\begin{align*}
\left( \frac{1}{1+x^2} \right)^{(n)} &=   {n! (-1)^n} \frac{i}{2} \left( \frac{1}{(x+i)^{n+1}} - \frac{1}{(x-i)^{n+1}} \right)\\
& = \frac{n! (-1)^n}{r^{2n+1}} {\sin[t(n+1)]}
\end{align*}

where $r=|x+i| = \sqrt{1+x^2}$, and, using the atan$2$ function, $t = \arctan (1/x)$. However, $\arctan (1/x)$ where $x \in (0,1)$ is complex valued for some $x$, so the $n$ th derivative of $1/(1+x^2)$ still remains complex and not only real valued in $(0, 1)$.

Comment: $\arctan(1/x)$ is real-valued for all non-zero $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: You're right I messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't we use a power series and differentiate termwise?
 $$f(x)=\frac {1}{1+x^2}=\sum_{\nu=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{\nu}x^{2 \nu}$$
$$f^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{\nu=n}^{\infty}(-1)^{\nu}\frac{(2 \nu)!}{(2\nu-n)!}x^{2 \nu -n}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$ i\left(\frac1z-\frac1{\overline z}\right)=i\frac{\overline z-z}{z\overline z}=\frac{2\operatorname{Im}(z)}{\|z\|^2}\in\Bbb R$$